# pm2 logs, print "PM2 Unknown id 77"

Tags: node.js, pm2

when I restart a process(nodejs) `pm2 restart 77`, it stucks with 'launching' status.

I `kill {processid}` to delete it because I can't delete it using `pm2 delete 77`.

But when I print logs `pm2 logs`, there is maybe a warning printed per second.

[image: pm2 logs]

what should I do to remove it?

Comment: Pm2 delete {name} or pm2 delete all

Comment: @Agnibha pm2 delete {name} can do nothing, and I don't want to delete all applications.

Comment: is your pm2 ls giving you the pids.. then you can kill them... and goto ~/.pm2/pids and then some file containing the pid. remove that..

Comment: ```pm2 delete 77``` show error ```Process 77 not found```, and I remove the file of ~/.pm2/pids, but it still appears Unknown id 77 , ```pm2 restart all``` as well.

Comment: I hava solved the problem. Just ```top``` search the node starred process, and compare with the```pm2 list``` pids, and I ```kill -9 {pid}``` which not exists in ```pm2 list```

Answer (score 12):

This is the simplest and most effective way.

```
pm2 save
pm2 kill
pm2 resurrect
```